# Gerrit is not able to authenticate using LDAP

Tags: ldap, gerrit, apacheds

I am using apacheds (running on port 10389) for LDAP services. My gerrit instance is able to to a handshake with LDAP, however, user authentication is never successful. I always get this error message:
username: name.surname
password: password

```
INFO  com.google.gerrit.httpd.auth.ldap.LdapLoginServlet : 'name.surname' failed to sign in: No such user: name.surname
```

My gerrit.conf is as follows:

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = /home/gerrit2/git
    canonicalWebUrl = http://gerrit.myorg.com:8080/
[database]
    type = mysql
    hostname = localhost
    database = reviewdb
    username = gerrit2
[index]
    type = LUCENE
[auth]
    type = LDAP
[ldap]
    server      = ldap://localhost:10389
    username    = cn=abc def,ou=user,dc=myorg,dc=com
    accountBase = ou=user,dc=myorg,dc=com
    groupBase   = ou=user,dc=myorg,dc=com
    referral    = follow
    accountFullName = cn
    accountEmailAddress = mail

[sendemail]
    smtpServer = localhost
[container]
    user = gerrit2
    javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.71.x86_64/jre
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = http://*:8080/
[cache]
    directory = cache
```

The ldif file through which I added the user into partition ou=user,dc=myorg,dc=com is:

```
dn: cn=name.surname,ou=user,dc=myorg,dc=com
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: top
cn: name.surname
description: Gerrit Administrator
sn: name.surname
mail: name.surname@myorg.com
userpassword: password
```

Can anyone explain where's the problem happening? I assume by default the gerrit username is matched against the CN (by appending against the baseDN). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I got the answer. By default username is matched against uid. To match username against CN, the following line has to be added to [ladp] subsection in gerrit.config file:

```
(cn=${username})
```

Comment: what variable was this associated with under the ldap subsection?